# Change documentroot on Apache 2.4

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apache-httpd

I knew how to do it on Apache 2.2, however, how do I change the document root on Apache 2.4?
I run Debian 8.20 on a Virtualbox VM as my apache server and Ubuntu 15.04 as my host OS.

I tried to change Document root on /ooo-default.conf to something like:
/home/www

I also guess that I have to do chmod –R 755 /home/www.
Inside of the directory is
However whenever I try to load my VM's IP in Firefox it just 404's.

Here is one run from the Apache error log:

```
[Wed Oct 28 20:05:38.708080 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5884] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 28 20:05:38.708142 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5884] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 28 20:05:52.281645 2015] [core:error] [pid 5887] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46927] AH00035: access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/home/www/index.php') be$
[Wed Oct 28 20:06:37.527726 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5884] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Now I am getting timeuts when trying to connect to my VM from my browser.

Comment: What does Apache's error log file tell you?

Comment: Here is my error log file: http://pastebin.com/5ejMKJMB

Answer (score 1):

Why don't set the DocumentRoot in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?
It is one and the same for all virtual hosts. If you set it in `000-default.conf` I think you will have to set it too in the other `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` the day you will create them.

To set the correct owner and permissions you have to know which user run the service. Anyway the read permission should be enough I think

The cause could be SElinux,

> SELinux is a Mandatory Access Control (MAC) system which is a kernel
>   (LSM) enhancement to confine programs to a limited set of resources.

I guess that one of its security policy avoid that apache2 user to read folders which are not under `/var/www/`, its not recommended to disable [it but it is possible](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-disable-httpd-selinux-security-protection/) , it depends on how you will use the VM (testing dev prod?).

Comment: I am just using it for practice. Also I don't see document root in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: lets test if the problem is SElinux first, disable it temporarily with `echo 0 > /selinux/enforce` or `setenforce 0` , restart apache2 and test again with browser. Temporarily mean until you restart the VM

Comment: Is it safe to turn off SELinux temporarily on my working machine?

Comment: You have to do it on the server (the virtual machine) , not on your local machine. No, as I said it is not recommended. But we are just checking/testing if this is your problem. Disabling it temporarily mean that this config is reset after the machine is reboot. So execute the test suggested in the previous comment. If this solve the problem, you will have to fix SElinux configuration, in order to allow apache2 to read only the folder `/home/www` and its subfolders

Comment: +1 for the SELinux bit. Nothing for setting the Document Root globally.

Comment: @Roaima : set the Docroot globally is a bad idea? thx for the info

Comment: @lese I wouldn't set the docroot globally for exactly the reason you suggested it should be set that way.

Comment: let me understand, the DocumentRoot is the same for each virtual host, right? Then why you would not set it globally?

Comment: @lese your machine, you do what you want. My machine, I do what I want. I like my vHosts to have separate document roots. Perhaps that's not necessary for you.

Comment: eheheh man, not necessary to get mad. I was trying to understand if it was useful somehow to set it in each VH. But regarding your reply, it seems it's not. Just a personal preference. Whatever

Comment: echo 0 > /selinux/enforce returned: no such file or directory. Does Debian 8.20 even have SELinux by default? The only thing that exists in my /etc/selinux folder is semanage.conf, and I don't know how to disable selinux from there.

Comment: did you try to run `setenforce 0` too?

Answer (score 1):

The clue is here

```
[Wed Oct 28 20:05:52.281645 2015] [core:error] [pid 5887] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:46927] AH00035: access to /index.php denied (filesystem path '/home/www/index.php')
```

Apache cannot access or run your `index.php`. Ensure the permissions on `/home` and `/home/www` are sufficient for Apache to access them and that `index.php` is readable too:

```
chmod a+rx / /home /home/www
chmod a+r /home/www/index.php
```

You will also need to review the access rights within the Apache configuration. Look for `<Directory>` or `<Location>` directives and ensure they match your new document root. Restart Apache as necessary.

---

If that doesn't solve the problem try disabling SELinux to test whether that's the issue. If it is, you can find out how to relax its access restrictions for Apache easily enough.

Comment: how exactly should the chmod command look?

Comment: alright chmod's did not work. How do I return them back to normal so I don't have a security hole?

Comment: @Mario why should you have a security hole?

Comment: misconfigured access rights. on my working machine.

Comment: @MarioKamenjak I've not given you any misconfigured access rights. Perhaps someone else has, but I can't see your system so I can't advise on that here.

Comment: echo 0 > /selinux/enforce returned: no such file or directory. Does Debian 8.20 even have SELinux by default? The only thing that exists in my /etc/selinux folder is semanage.conf, and I don't know how to disable selinux from there.

Comment: does debian even have apparmor or tomoyo?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps.

- Change document root in 000-default.conf.
- Restart apache2

Thanks

Comment: I retried that again, now on my Ubuntu local machine, however now I get 403 errors.

Comment: 403 is access denied, You should check the ownership and permission of your project directory

Comment: to what should I set it?

Comment: You should try with 766

Comment: @Shabir why would permissions of 0766 make an improvement over 0755?

Comment: I am still getting 403...

Comment: Here is my error log file: http://pastebin.com/5ejMKJMB