# Apache/Nginx document root environment-variable

Tags: debian, arch-linux, apache-httpd, environment-variables, stability

Apache/Nginx "default" document root path is usally `/var/www/html` but theoretically this could change tomorrow.

Having a distro-default and communally-maintained environment variable for it (instead of creating one myself, lowercased of course so I won't clash with existing uppercase envars) **would ease me much** because then I wouldn't need to do:

```
cat <<-EOF >> "$HOME"/.profile
    export drt="/var/www/html"

    drt() {
        cd $drt/
    }
EOF
```

Does document root have an envar in any common distro? Especially Debian/Arch?

Comment: Why a downvote? Aren't some envars differ between distros and adjusted to very popular software?

Comment: Re: Debian & Apache, I can't find one yet. See https://sources.debian.org/src/apache2/2.4.37-1/debian/config-dir/sites-available/000-default.conf/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239298/117549 and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372 (that's as far as I went)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea, since I found no evidence of an environment variable -- just default configurations in the various distributions:

```
case $(lsb_release -i) in
  (*Debian) conf=/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf;;
  (*Arch)   conf=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf;;
esac
awk '/^[^#]*DocumentRoot/ { print "export drt=\""$2"\"" ORS 
                                  "drt() {" ORS 
                                  "  cd \"$drt\"/" ORS 
                                  "}" }' "$conf" >> "$HOME"/.profile
```

Each distribution can [decide what it wants for defaults](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372), so even the above method requires knowing where the base HTTPD configuration files are.

Answer (score 1):

In Debian there are a bunch of Apache environment variables, but none for the document root.

What `/usr/sbin/apachectl` does is:

1. look for `APACHE_CONFDIR` and set it to default value `/etc/apache2` if not set.
2. look for `APACHE_ENVVARS` (the environment variable file) and set it to default value `"$APACHE_CONFDIR/envvars"` if not set. this file is then sourced.
3. modify `APACHE_ARGUMENTS` to include the path to the config directory if it was overridden.
4. set default path to the binary `/usr/sbin/apache2`
5. set a few other variables...

The default environment variable file contains these variables:

```
root@x250:/# grep export /etc/apache2/envvars
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX/apache2.pid
export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX
export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX
export LANG=C
export LANG
#export APACHE_LYNX='www-browser -dump'
#export APACHE_ARGUMENTS=''
#export APACHE2_MAINTSCRIPT_DEBUG=1
```

So you could

- add variable "`MY_HACKED_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT`" to `/etc/apache2/envvars` and modify your *.conf files
- or smuggle in your path through `APACHE_ARGUMENTS` and check it/set it in your modified *.conf with `<IfDefine>`
- or change the config directory `APACHE_CONFDIR` to a different path
- or include a config file for a `<VirtualHost>` with a different `DocumentRoot`
- or symlink `/var/www/html` to a different directory
- ...

There are so many options! And honestly, I don't really think the debian guys will change `/var/www/html` in the near future. Why would they?

But if they do, you will probably see something like

> This is the default welcome page used to test the correct operation of the Apache2 server after installation on Debian systems.
>   If you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed at this site is working properly. You should **replace this file** (located at /xxx/yyy/html/index.html) before continuing to operate your HTTP server.

Sorry, I can't tell how it's done in nginx.